# What exactly is going on in Proc::Background?

Tags: windows, perl, automation, background-process, strawberry-perl

I am trying to write a script that automates other perl scripts.  Essentially, I have a few scripts that rollup data for me and need to be run weekly.  I also have a couple that need to be run on the weekend to check things and email me if there is a problem.  I have the email worked out and everything but the automation.  Judging by an internet search, it seems as though using Proc::Background is the way to go.  I tried writing a very basic script to test it and can't quite figure it out.  I am pretty new to Perl and have never automated anything before (other than through windows task scheduler), so I really don't understand what the code is saying.

My code:

```
use Proc::Background;

$command = "C:/strawberry/runDir/SendMail.pl";


my $proc1 = Proc::Background -> new($command);
```

I receive an error that says `no executable program located at C:...` Can someone explain to me what exactly the code (Proc::Background) is doing?  I will then at least have a better idea of how to accomplish my task and debug in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have better luck with `\ ` instead of `/`? The shell isn't as flexible as the OS itself. (Don't forget to double the `\ ` in the literal: `"c:\\st..."`.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by throwing 'perl' at the beginning.  I'll update the post in a second.

Answer (score 2):

I did notice on Proc::Background's documentation the following:

> The Win32::Process module is always used to spawn background processes
>   on the Win32 platform.  This module always takes a single string
>   argument containing the executable's name and any option arguments. 
>   In addition, it requires that the absolute path to the executable is
>   also passed to it.  If only a single argument is passed to new, then
>   it is split on whitespace into an array and the first element of the
>   split array is used at the executable's name.  If multiple arguments
>   are passed to new, then the first element is used as the executable's
>   name.

So, it looks like it requires an executable, which a Perl script would not be, but "perl.exe" would be.

I typically specify the "perl.exe" in my Windows tasks as well:

```
C:\dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe "C:\Dropbox\Programming\Perl\mccabe.pl"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got the command to work by throwing "perl" in front of it so it looks like this: '$command = "perl C:/strawberry/runDir/cmd.pl"'